# How to handle iOS App session timeouts using Java and Appium in Mobile Native

Tags: java, ios, testing, automation, appium

I am working on an app, where i get a timeout after certain period of inactivity. I want to capture that and click on 'Continue' when that alert comes up so that the test is not interrupted.

Since this alert is not triggered by any action, it is challenging to predict when this occurs. Any suggestions on how this can be handled?

Performing a check like below after each and every step doesn't look like an ideal solution.

```
if (alert.exists()){
button.click;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try smth like this:

```
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            try {
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
                driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("   no alert visible after 30 sec.");
            }
```